# How to use CASE in Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

I Have one doubt regarding CASE in Apache Drill.

I am trying to use `CASE` in latest version of drill (1.9) in Window system & in embedded mode.

**SEE My Query:-**

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN 
EXISTS
(SELECT distinct CS.ProviderID
 FROM <pluginName>.<dbName>.<schemaName>.<tableName1> AS `CS` 
INNER JOIN <pluginName>.<dbName>.<schemaName>.<tableName2> AS `PS` 
ON PS.ID = CS.ProviderID 
where CS.PluginName = 'some text from db' AND 
PS.Code = 'SQLSERVER' AND CS.AccessKey = 'B2S1' limit 1)
THEN 
(SELECT distinct b.`Value` from <pluginName>.<dbName>.<schemaName>.<tableName3> AS a 
inner join <pluginName>.<dbName>.<schemaName>.<tableName4> as b
 on a.ID = b.PermissionID 
inner join <pluginName>.<dbName>.<schemaName>.<tableName5> as c
 on c.RoleID=b.RoleID and c.ModuleID=1 limit 1)
ELSE 0
END FROM  <pluginName>.<dbName>.<schemaName>.<tableName3>;
```

I am trying to execute this query but it throughing error.

**ERROR:-**

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION
>   ERROR: From line 2, column 1 to line 7, column 4: Illegal mixing of
>   types in CASE or COALESCE statement SQL Query null

**What i am doing wrong in this query.?**

Answer (score 0):

In Apache-drill you cannot use select statement inside case. In fact you cannot use inner select statement for a column at all.

Try taking the inner select as a separate table and join with main table, that should work.